# Graphics Row vs Column Major Transformations

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, linear-algebra, directx-11

This has puzzled me for a long time. Why do most graphics APIs (DirectX with HLSL and OpenGL) usually represent things such that position and normal vectors are row vectors? This is opposite the typical form seem in a math class. Both are correct mathematically, I'm just curious about why graphics guys chose this representation. Let me explain...

### Efficiency of the multiplication of a vector and matrix:

In my mind the row-vector `x` and transformation matrix 'A' are multiplied as `x*A` which leads to `y=x*a' being

```
y[0] = x[0]*M[0][0] + x[1]*M[1][0] + x[2]*M[2][0] + x[3]*M[3][0];
y[1] = x[0]*M[0][1] + x[1]*M[1][1] + x[2]*M[2][1] + x[3]*M[3][1];
y[2] = x[0]*M[0][2] + x[1]*M[1][2] + x[2]*M[2][2] + x[3]*M[3][2];
y[3] = x[0]*M[0][3] + x[1]*M[1][3] + x[2]*M[2][3] + x[3]*M[3][3];
```

Notice that to get `y[0]` the matrix's first column must be read. Isn't this less efficient than reading the first row instead? The matrix is typically stored "row-major." **I will accert that `A*x` is more efficient than `x*A` because of positions in memory. Is this wrong?**

### Computation of the matrix elements

To further complicate, the typical way of creating the transformation matrix (for example using the DirectX Math library) populates the matrix in the form

```
| R00 R01 R02 0 |
| R10 R11 R12 0 |
| R20 R21 R22 0 |
| T0  T1  T2  1 |
```

where `R` denotes the rotation/scaling terms and `T` denotes the translation terms. This form is intended for multiplication in the form `x*A = y`. **Why does the math library not provide the transpose of this matrix such that `A*x = y` can be computed without manually transposing the result of the math library matrix construction?**

### Summary

The matrix created by the directx math library seems to set up a less efficient transformation than the transpose of said matrix. Am I wrong in this conclusion or is there an overlying reason?

Comment: With DirectX 11, you should be using [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) rather than legacy D3DXMath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row-major order allows creating affine transformations in the left-to-right order from basic transformations. For example this way:

```
M = Scale * Rotation * Translation
```

Agreeing with order of execution.
Of course basic transformations must be transposed vs. definitions from linear algebra. In column-major order used in math, the order in which transformations are executed is reversed and counterintuitive.
The efficency of both approches could be identical (it depends on the order in which tables are stored in memory).
Using column-major matrices in graphics is therefore only the result of linear algebra standard.

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL actually uses column-major matrices. Everything you have described is specific to D3DX. Even HLSL uses column-major matrices by default.

To address your other concern, vectors are treated as row or column in HLSL depending on which side of the `mul (x,y)` statement they occur in (row vector if `x`, column vector if `y`). It is the same in GLSL, except GLSL actually has a `*` operator for matrix multiplication.

> #### [GLSL 4.50 Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf#page=109)  -  5 Operators and Expressions  -  p. 103
>
> > The operator is multiply (*), where both operands are matrices or one operand is a vector and the
> >     other a matrix. A right vector operand is treated as a column vector and a left vector operand as a
> >     row vector. In all these cases, it is required that the number of columns of the left operand is equal
> >     to the number of rows of the right operand. Then, the multiply (*) operation does a linear
> >     algebraic multiply, yielding an object that has the same number of rows as the left operand and the
> >     same number of columns as the right operand. Section 5.10 “Vector and Matrix Operations”
> >     explains in more detail how vectors and matrices are operated on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware that the HLSL `mul (x,y)` supports left and right multiplication, but why do most tutorials use `x*A` and why does the D3D math library product a matrix suited for `x*A` is `A*x` seems more efficient?

Comment: The document you posted seems to support my claim that right multiplication (`A*x`) is the preferred method for performance.

Comment: @RussellTrahan: Well, consider what the columns in a transformation matrix represent... in the model view matrix, you have the first 3 ***columns*** representing the orientation of the axes and the 4th column represents translation. SIMD matrix operations and caching are more efficient when you can fetch an entire column with a contiguous memory fetch. Alternatively, if you wanted to pick out the translation (4th column) of your model view matrix in row-major form you would have to fetch all 4 rows.

Comment: It seems that you are saying that the view matrix is the transpose of what the directx math library provides using build-in functions.  The way I wrote it in the question is how it is provided. Other than that, you are only reinforcing my concern.

Comment: @RussellTrahan: One thing you have to account as well is, that the typical mathematical notation goes contrary to the memory layout of C style multidimensional arrays. So when you read C code you have mentally transpose the matrices; but of course transposition also swaps the order of operands. Now from a convenience point of view, column major *is* a lot of nicer to work with, and typically we use column vectors for vertex attributes and the used matrix multiplication convention *is* r-associative (A·c, and A_n·…·A_1·A_0·c).

Comment: @RussellTrahan: The D3DX math library stores everything row-major and then that matrix is passed to HLSL, which expects the matrix in column-major layout (so it receives a transposed matrix). Left-multiplying a row-major (transposed column-major) matrix is the same as right-multiplying a column-major matrix, this is why you see most HLSL shaders in tutorials do `mul (vector,matrix)`. If you were to properly transpose that matrix (so that both the math library and HLSL were using a column-major matrix), then you would need to right-multiply.

Comment: Direct3D's legacy fixed-function T&L pipeline was specifically row-major, left-handed but Direct3D does not have any particular handedness for the programmable pipeline. DirectXMath supports both row-major, left-handed and row-major, right-handed since it's just a convention choice. Historically most Direct3D apps use row-major LH, but XNA Game Studio used row-major RH. As noted, the HLSL compiler prefers to get matrices as column-major but LH/RH is just a convention you have to set for your code.

Comment: But no one addressed THIS part of question: "Why does the math library not provide the transpose of this matrix such that A*x = y can be computed without manually transposing the result of the math library matrix construction?"   Consider DirectX::XMMatrixTranslationFromVector()