# Matrix struct gives wrong output

Tags: c#, matrix, vector

In .Net Framework 4.6.2 (and earlier), there the `Matrix4x4` struct in the `System.Numerics` namespace.
The struct has a property `Translation` which is obviously used to store the translational part.
However, when using this property, it stores the values in the last row

Example:

```
var test = Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(1, 2, 3));
```

yields the following matrix:

> 1, 0, 0, 0
>
> 0, 1, 0, 0
>
> 0, 0, 1, 0
>
> 1, 2, 3, 1

But it should be

> 1, 0, 0, 1
>
> 0, 1, 0, 2
>
> 0, 0, 1, 3
>
> 0 ,0 ,0 ,1

in my opinion.

Is this a bug or is there something I completely got wrong?

Comment: Why are you mentioning the `.Net Framework` version, are you saying that you are getting different results with an higher version?

Comment: I just mentioned it because I wanted to make it reproducable for you

Comment: I'm sure you mean C# 6, .NET Framework 4.6.2 and rather the method `Matrix4x4.CreateScale(System.Numerics.Vector3 scales);`
[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4.createscale?view=netframework-4.8)

This gives the matrix you have shown.

By the way the outcome is the same for .NET Core 3.0

Comment: hello Faenrig, you mean that gives me the second matrix above?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have just tried both methods and `CreateScale` gives exactly the second matrix you mentioned.

Comment: No, `CreateScale` does not give you the matrix the OP wants. The diagonals are not 1, for starters.

Comment: canton7 I agree with you

Comment: Right, I have overseen that. Sorry.

Comment: On the same page you can use `Matrix4x4.Transpose(Matrix4x4)` to get that second matrix.
My best guess of this isn't that it's a bug, but it needs time to get a full answer on that.

Comment: I'll wait for the answer ;) Transposing a matrix where it should not be necessary (as seen from a mathemathical background) is not useful. All other methods/properties seem to work fine and are in consens with standard mathematical notations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The translation matrix is "transposed" because System.Numerics defines **row** vectors:

> For matrix transformations, the Vector2, Vector3, and Vector4
>   instances are represented as rows: a vector v is transformed by a
>   matrix M with vM multiplication.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector4?view=netframework-4.8))

The mathematics is as follows:

```
            / 1 0 0 0 \
[a b c 1] * | 0 1 0 0 | = [a+A b+B c+C 1]
            | 0 0 1 0 |
            \ A B C 1 /
```

Comment: thanks, a wonder that microsoft decided to transpose all their matrix stuff. I had a look at the source code and everything is transposed?!

Comment: @Vectorboy There are lots of discussions about this topic on the net. For example: https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/row-major-vs-column-major-row-vectors-vs-column-vectors/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234572/600135